# screenOrientation to fullsensor got error in Manifest

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am trying to work on a project that will work on 4 orientations. I set it on `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`, it works but it only does 3 orientation. So i set it to `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` for 4 orientation. Unfortunately, i got this error

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 
 'fullSensor').
```

Anybody knows how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullSensor is supported only from API level 9.

```
The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor for any of the 4 orientations. This is similar to "sensor" except this allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations, regardless of what the device will normally do (for example, some devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those). Added in API level 9.
```

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html.

Comment: i already set to API 9 and but the image still not totally flipped upside down. the phone(status bar) is upside down but the app is still not.

Comment: did you try "sensorLandscape" or "sensorPortrait" individually?

Comment: i got this error "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 
 'sensorPortrait')."

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> Did you give this in the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Which API level you are using ?

**fullSensor** is added in API level 9. [Check it once](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)

Comment: i already set to API 9 and but the image still not totally flipped upside down. the phone(status bar) is upside down but the app is still not.