# Expecting `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"` or `"fullSensor"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

i updated android studio to 3.6 and updated gradle as well and having this error below

[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBoM.png)

**LOG PRINT**

> Error:(117, 13) Expecting `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"` or
>   `"fullSensor"` for this activity so the user can use the application
>   in any orientation and provide a great experience on Chrome OS
>   devices.

i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919425/screenorientation-to-fullsensor-got-error-in-manifest) solution but did't help me and this is answered 7 years ago for api level 9 and i am using API level 28

Comment: This is google, they often do something strange. I suppose you can use 
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" to ignore this error for now. Probably in the future we will find some solution for it.

Comment: yes i tried and its worked but i think disabling the inspection related to Chrome OS will be better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable the check, here's how :

1. Go to Settings -> Inspection
2. Find "Chrome OS" (you can use the search bar on top left)
3. Disable everything (see image below)
4. Done

[image: Disable Chrome OS Checking]

Answer (score 3):

Easily add following lines to `<manifest>` tag of your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```